# Why OnCollisionEnter2D / OnTriggerEnter2D don't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        {
            live1--;
   }
```

}

All was ok. But now, I turned on `Is Trigger` in my `Circle Collider2D`. So, my game object doesn't collide and `live--` don't work.

Answer (score 2):

IsTrigger propety fires  OnTriggerEnter, OnTriggerExit and OnTriggerStay  events and doesn't register for collision. If you want to use IsTrigger you must change OnCollisionEnter2D to OnTriggerEnter2D.

Answer (score 1):

OnCollision events and OnTrigger events are mutually exclusive, they can fire one or the other from an object at a time, but not both.

From OnTriggerEnter docs:

```
Trigger events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a rigidbody attached.
```

From OnCollisionEnter docs:

```
Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic 
rigidbody attached.
```

Comment: Rigidbody attached

Comment: You can't have both collision and trigger. You need to choose one or the other.